# YouTube Analytics API: video + day aggregation. Is it possible?

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api

I have a YouTube channel and I want to extract the video information (likes, dislikes, views, subscribes, unsubscribes, visualization time, etc) with a daily aggregation from my own channel. I have read in some posts/blogs it is possible to do this, but I haven't been able to find the information on the YouTube Analytics API.

In fact, when I try to select in the API Explorer on YouTube API page the dimensions of 'day' and 'video', it returns an error saying the query is not supported.

[image]

This doesn't happen when I use only the dimension of day, for example:

[image]

I have tried this in Python and it isn't working either. Is there any way to get this information or would I have to download it from the YouTube Analytics statistics directly day by day?

This is the code I used:

```
import googleapiclient.errors
import os
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"]

def main():
    # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
    # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
    #os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

    api_service_name = "youtubeAnalytics"
    api_version = "v2"
    client_secrets_file = "supercliente.json"

    # Get credentials and create an API client
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        client_secrets_file, scopes)
    credentials = flow.run_console()
    youtube_analytics = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)

    request = youtube_analytics.reports().query(
        dimensions="day,video",
        endDate="2022-05-01",
        ids="channel==MINE",
        maxResults=50,
        metrics="likes",
        startDate="2021-03-01",
    )
    response = request.execute()

    print(response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The error I get:

```
HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://youtubeanalytics.googleapis.com/v2/reports?dimensions=day&endDate=2022-05-01&ids=channel%3D%3DMINE&maxResults=50&metrics=likes&startDate=2021-03-01&filters=vBDX3bljsGw&alt=json returned "Could not parse content (N/A) of field parameters.filters.". Details: "[{'message': 'Could not parse content (N/A) of field parameters.filters.', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'badRequest'}]">
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example] what call are you making

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't working because I needed to add the video dimension as filter with a list of the video ids. Now I can get the daily metrics:

import googleapiclient.errors
import os
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

```
scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"]

def main():
    # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
    # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
    #os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

    api_service_name = "youtubeAnalytics"
    api_version = "v2"
    client_secrets_file = "superclient.json"

    # Get credentials and create an API client
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        client_secrets_file, scopes)
    credentials = flow.run_console()
    youtube_analytics = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)

    request = youtube_analytics.reports().query(
        dimensions="day",
        endDate="2022-05-01",
        ids="channel==MINE",
        maxResults=50,
        metrics="views",
        filters = 'video==PWSkHW17H_6',
        startDate="2021-03-01"
    )
    response = request.execute()

    print(response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```